# pl/sql. View is too long execution

Tags: oracle, performance, view, query-optimization

I have a view which contains two `select` joined by `union`. When I do `select * from view_name`, it's executed too long.
But when I execute just content of this view(two select with union), it outputs result too quickly.
What it is can be problem with view?

```
Create or replace view view_name as   
    select * from (
        select ... from table_1 
        join table_1 n on .. 
        join table_2 o on .. 
        join table_3 rr on .. 
        join table_4 t on .. 
        join table_5 cc on ..    
        where ...
    union    
        select ... from table_6 sdpd
        join table_7 sdp on ... 
        join table_8 sdo on ...
        join table_9 nom on ...
        join table_10 rr on .
        join table_11 t on  ...
        join table_12 cc on ...
        where ... group by ... 
    ) order by 1,2
```

Comment: Can you please post how did you created your view. Post the query.

Comment: pls, help, it's too importent.

Comment: Second execution may use the cached results. Are you sure that the query execution is fast at its first call.